# how to detect all overlapping peaks in rstudio with getWaveletPeaks

Tags: r, detect, overlapping

[image]I have received a code to plot, detect peaks and analyse a NMR spectra in Rstudio. It works pretty much as I would want it to, but at the peak picking i struggle. The code include the getWaveletPeaks function and I'm having huge trubble figuring out how to detect peaks in close proximity and especially overlapping peaks (ALL local max). Can I detect ALL local max points with this function and in that case How?

Comment: Could you provide a **minimal** reproducible example of your issue? That is, data + code + output produced, as well as explicitly stating the _desired_ output and any problems (e.g., errors, deviations from desired output) you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you the whole info right now and it seems as if i only can add one image? However, in the image added you can see a nice part of the spectra with several peaks and also the dots representing the local maxima detected for all spectra (29 overlayed in total). My problem is that, no matter what I seem to be able to change, some peaks are not detected (example 2.055 ppm). The part in the code that I believe does not work as I wish is this:

```
enter code here

peaks <- speaq::getWaveletPeaks(Y.spec=Spectra,
                                 X.ppm=ppm, 
                                 window.width = "small",
                                 window.split = 64,                                            
                                 baselineThresh = 2,                                        
                                 SNR.Th = 7,                                           
                                 nCPU = 6,                                                 
                                 include_nearbyPeaks = TRUE)                                
save(peaks,file='BiGh_191009_neuro_csf_800_peaks_snr10_bt10.Rdata')
```